# Configuring SharePoint database server on Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, windows-7

I am trying to install SharePoint Foundation 2010 on Windows 7 Home Premium. The installation completed successfully. When I try to access the administrative interface it says "Page not found". I can see that the database is also configured with the same new account in SQL Server, and it looks like the tables were created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google search for "sharepoint windows 7 home premium" produces several results that may be helpful:

[Enable SharePoint 2010 in Windows 7 Home Premium](http://stringwriter.com/2011/06/06/enable-sharepoint-2010-in-windows-7-home-premium/)

[SharePoint Foundation on Windows 7 Home Premium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384607/sharepoint-foundation-on-windows-7-home-premium)

[So you think you can’t install SharePoint 2010 on Windows 7 Home Premium?](http://www.rl-soft.com/en/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=21)

Comment: Thanx.. Rob thses link were help full and resolved my issue.